# How to calculate the integral of $\vec{a}\cdot\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec{a})$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, multiple-integral

I want to calculate the following integral:
$$S = \int\vec{a}\cdot\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec{a})\,\text{d}V$$

I tried to calculate the integral of the $i$-th term, i. e., $\int a_i\partial_i(\nabla\cdot\vec{a})\,\text{d}V$, but I got to this expression
$$S = \int a_i\partial_i(\partial_ja_j)\,\text{d}V=a_i\partial_ja_j-\int(\partial_ia_i)(\partial_ja_j)\,\text{d}V$$
where the first term on the right side turns to be a vector. What am I doing wrong? I know that the result is
$$S = \int\vec{a}\cdot\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec{a})\,\text{d}V=\text{something}-\int(\nabla\cdot\vec{a})^2\,\text{d}V$$
so I guess that the only problem with my calculation is on that first term.

Comment: Hint: $\int\nabla\cdot\vec{v}dV$ can be evaluated by the divergence theorem.

Comment: @J.G. but I don't have an integral like that

Comment: Oh, but you do. If $I,\,J$ are integrals for which integration by parts says $I=B-J$ with $B$ a boundary term, you can write $B$ as the integral $I+J$, which simplifies as above.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I can write the sum of those two volume integrals as an volume integral of the divergence of $(\nabla\cdot\vec{a})\vec{a}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply the divergence theorem (or integration by parts), you get that
$$ S = \int_V a \cdot \nabla(\nabla \cdot a) dV = \int_{\partial V} (\nabla \cdot a) a \cdot n dS - \int_V (\nabla \cdot a)^2 dV, $$
where $n$ denotes a normalized pointing outward normal vector orthogonal to the boundary $\partial V$.